# Is there a way to forbid overriding a member in a mixin?

Tags: scala, mixins

So, I have a bunch of stackable traits defined, like this:

```
trait Base { 
  val prefix: String = ""
  def foo = ""
}

trait Foo extends Base { 
  override def foo = prefix + "/Foo" + ";" + super.foo
}

trait Bar extends Base {
  override def foo = prefix + "/Bar" + ";" + super.foo
}

class Bat extends Foo with Bar {
  override val prefix: String = "Bat"
}

new Bat().foo
```

The above returns `Bat/Bar;Bat/Foo`, this is what I want.
Now, the problem is, of course, that there can only be one instance of `prefix`, and, if one of the mixins tries to override it, it won't work, because the one defined in `Bat` "trumps" it. This is ok, except, I would like the "won't work" thing to be explicit.

Can anyone think of some kind of a trick, that would make attempting to override `prefix` in a trait rather than in a class inheriting from it to cause a compilation error?

Comment: You could mark `prefix` as `final` but you won't be able then to override it in `Bat` either.

Comment: @EndeNeu yeah, figured _that_ much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the trait in two and leverage [explicitly typed self-references](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html), like this:

```
trait Base {
  def foo = ""
}

trait Prefix {
  val prefix: String = ""
}

trait Foo extends Base { this: Prefix =>
  override def foo = prefix + "/Foo" + ";" + super.foo
}

trait Bar extends Base { this: Prefix =>
  override def foo = prefix + "/Bar" + ";" + super.foo
}

class Bat extends Prefix with Foo with Bar {
  override val prefix: String = "Bat"
}

new Bat().foo
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps. There is nothing preventing me from doing `trait Bar extends Base with Prefix`, and overriding `prefix` there, which is exactly what I am trying to restrict.

Comment: Yes, the current suggestion would only work if you follow a certain workflow. One way to provide a safer guarantee would be to mark `Prefix` as `sealed` and leave the `Foo` and `Bar` traits in another file. I can edit my answer in this direction if you feel it would tackle the problem better.

Comment: Not trying to be difficult, but I don't want it to be sealed :) Think of `Base` as, some default http routing implementaion, providing common features, like authorization etc. `Foo` and `Bar` then are  routings to concrete services (e.g., user profile, admin interface, storage, etc.), that can be provided by one or more servers. `Bat` is the web server. It mixes `Foo` and `Bar` (and possibly others) in to create the routings, and defines `prefix` as the mount point. Now, you can see, why I don't want `Prefix` to be sealed - there are many different servers, we don't want them all in one file.

Answer (score 0):

Since traits can extend classes, there's no way to forbid traits to have an overriden definition of prefix, but allow classes to have one.

And btw, about the "won't work" part, I disagree, it's working as expected. I'm pretty sure a developer overriding an attribute is fully conscious that she's well...overriding what she inherits.

And what about classes inheriting classes anyway ?

The only thing to do if you want to forbid inheritance, is to mark the  val/def final in any Trait or Class that actually don't want it to be further overriden (in your example, that'd be Foo and Bar).

Comment: I am willing to live with traits extending classes as an exception. First, because it's more like a weird corner case, that doesn't occur all that often, and second, because those traits wouldn't really be stackable anyway (you can't mix in more than one), so it is not really much of a factor here.

Comment: It's just a point to show that the language won't allow you to restrict inheritance to classes. The fact that it's possible (used or not) proves that you won't achieve what you want.

Comment: Not sure how the fact that something is possible demonstrates that something _else_ isn't, but that's ok. Regarding "developer overriding the attribute ...", this is true as a philosophical concept, but does not help very much in practice, especially when stacking and multiple inheritance is involved. A developer assigning a `String` to an `Int` should be aware about possible problems it may cause as well. Would you use that as an argument against strict typing and compile-time type safety? 

Classes inheriting classes is fine because they don't stack.

Comment: I don't want to argue. I tried to explain in my answer why what you want isn't doable, if you're not satisfied with this answer, feel free to downvote it :)

Comment: Well, I did not ask why it wasn't doable :) It certainly _possible_ to make it doable, despite any of your arguments, which, frankly, just don't seem applicable here at all. Yes traits can extend classes, and classes can extend classes ... I don't see what any of this have to do with a possibility of restricting a particular member to only be defined in a (non-abstract) class.

Comment: As trait can extend classes, this particular member can be defined in any trait extend a non-abstract class defining the particular member. Hence, if class can define the member, traits can too (by inheritance).

Comment: Obviously, by "define a member" I mean define it explicitly, not by inheritance. The fact, that you can define a member in a class, and then extend it by a trait is inconsequential: the idea here is to prevent multiple definitions from being mixed-in by stacked traits. Linear inheritance from classes is not a problem.